# Scraping a website with same url for different pages

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping

So, I need to scrape this website which has a table like feature with limited number of results(say N) displayed per page. There is a next button to move to next N results but the url remains same. Wondering how to scrape it ?

URL - https://ehservices.publichealth.lacounty.gov/ezsearch

Also, there are javascript void sublinks in all of these entries in the results that I need to be able to click and scrape. How do I do this ?

Before I create a complicated solution, wanted to know if there is library to do this simply ?

Comment: The best library for scraping a website is `wget` in my opinion. However if you need to scrape a website rich in javascript, with many ajax requests you better go with `phantom.js`. What do you mean by "There is a next button to move to next N results but the url remains same" ? The pagination is being performed by ajax?

Comment: yes, the pagination, heck almost everything is done by AJAX at this url.

Comment: Even if this is performed by AJAX, you can still try with `wget`. Open your developer console and check the XHR request while you click on the pages. This should be a normal GET request (the only difference is that is being performed as a AJAX request). If you can check how the web site is mounting its pagination, you can mimic with wget

i.e wget www.mypage.com?p=1

Use `man wget` to get all info you need to scrape with wget